# Error while opening a SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: sharepoint-2013, object-reference

I migrated MOSS 2007 Environment to SharePoint Server 2010, then to SharePoint Server 2013. I have a list called "Cash Receipts Tracker". Some list items contains PDF attachment. This list item can be viewed and edited in SP2010 without any error.  But list item cannot be viewed or edited in SP2013. I can view all the list items at once but not individually. It does not have any workflow associated with it.

When I try to open the list item, I get error like this.

Application error when access /abi/finance/CashReceiptsTracker/Lists/Cash Receipts Tracker/DispForm.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListFieldIterator.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.TemplateBasedControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I don't know what to do now. Help Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem.  What I had to so was go into SharePoint Designer and recreate the Display and Edit forms.  I'm not sure how they got corrupt in the first place, but recreating the forms worked.